# pandas apply typeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, apply, series, array-broadcasting

I have a dataframe `df_tr` like this:

```
      item_id    target   target_sum  target_count
0        0          0           1            50            
1        0          0           1            50
```

I'm trying to find the mean of the target but excluding the target value of the current row, and put the mean value in a new column. The result would be:

```
     item_id    target   target_sum  target_count item_id_mean_target
0        0          0           1            50           0.02041
1        0          0           1            50           0.02041
```

where I computed `item_id_mean_target` value from the formula:

```
target_sum - target/target_count - 1
```

...with this code:

```
df_tr['item_id_mean_target'] = df_tr.target.apply(lambda x: (x['target_sum']-x)/(x['target_count']-1))
```

I think my solution is correct but instead I got:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for apply here, pandas (and therefore numpy) broadcasts operations.

```
df['item_id_mean_target'] = (df.target_sum - df.target) / (df.target_count - 1)
```

```
df

   item_id  target  target_sum  target_count  item_id_mean_target
0        0       0           1            50             0.020408
1        0       0           1            50             0.020408
```

As for why your error occurs, you are calling `apply` on a `pd.Series` object, therefore, you cannot reference any other columns inside the `apply` (since it only receives scalar values).

To fix it, you'd need to do `df.apply(...)` but at that point, you're penalised with low performance, so, I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the sum and count columns and using `groupby` to derive them:

```
df_tr.groupby('item_id').apply(lambda x: (x['target'].sum() - x['target'])     
                                         / (x['target'].count() - 1))
```

You may also notice the issue in your original statement where you had `x['target_sum']-x`.  It should have been `x['target_sum']-x['target']`.

Comment: Smart, you've gone beyond the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df_tr.apply(lambda x:(x['target_sum']-x)/(x['target_count']-1), axis=1)
```

Comment: This works, but is slow compared to a purely vectorised operation.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.